# get wrong output of a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

```
    public static int getIndexOf(char ch, String str) {
    if (str == null || str.equals("")) {
        return 0;
     //base case
    }else{
        char first = str.charAt(0);
        if (ch != first) {
            return -1;
     //returns -1 when the character cannot be found within the string
        }else{
            int rest = str.length() - 1;
            if (str.charAt(rest) == ch) {
                return rest; 
            }
            return lastIndexOf(ch, str.substring(0, rest));
            //recursive case
        }
    }
}
```

This my method which returns the index of the input character of the input string.  However, when I run it in the interaction plane, it returns wrong number.  For example, when I enter 'a' and "peach", it is supposed to return 2, but it returns -1.  This method should return -1 only when the character cannot be found in the string.  Can anyone tell me how to deal with it?
Thank you!

Comment: First of all, why aren't you using string.indexOf(char); ??

Comment: If you want the index of `a` in `peach`, you'll jump into the `else` block (because `peach` is not `null` and it's not equal to `""`). There the first character (`p`) is compared to `a`, which are not equal. Therfore the `if` condition is `true` and your method will return `-1`.

Comment: Second of all, of course you are getting a -1 instead of two... you execute that method and if returns -1 when ch != first

Answer (score 1):

Well why don't you step through the logic and see what happens.

```
getIndexOf('a', "peach")
```

Method goes in, string isn't null or empty so it falls through to the next line of code.

```
char first = str.charAt(0); // this is 'p'

if (ch != first) {  // is 'p' equal to 'a'? no. so return -1
        return -1;
```

And then the rest of your logic will never execute. Can you see how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

your following portion of code means that it will check for the first character of the string if it is matching otherwise it will return -1.

```
char first = str.charAt(0);
        if (ch != first) {
            return -1;
```

this says that if character at 0th index doesn't match then send -1 so as 'p' in "peach" isn't matching with 'a' so it is return -1.

did you get it?

Comment: Yes, but how do I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The output's not wrong, the implementation is!

Think in words first.  If the desired character is the first character in the string, then the result is zero.  Otherwise it's (1 + the index in the string that remains after cutting off the first character).  Now code the words:

```
return (str.charAt(0) == ch) ? 0 : 1 + getIndexOf(ch, str.substring(1));
```

This doesn't yet handle the case where the character is not in the string at all. Here the `charAt(0)` call will eventually throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `str` doesn't have one!

The cleanest way to handle this case is to catch the exception.  So you's have two functions: `mustGetIndexOf`, which is the recursive relation above, and `getIndexOf`, which calls the one above inside a `try {} catch() {}`, returning -1 in that case.

Of course if you don't want to allow the exception, you can test the recursive call's result with `if` for the special case of `-1`.  The code is uglier, but it will work.  Whenever a `-1` is seen, return `-1` again.  This propagates the `-1` all the way back to the caller.  The exception "unwinds" the recursive calls on the stack in a similar manner, just with one chop instead of the gradual call-by-call way your `if` statements will do it.

I won't give you full code so you can continue to learn.